# Why was my 2021 US IRS Head of Household tax return (1040), submitted via free file fillable forms, rejected?

Tags: xml, schema, irs

The error:

Issue : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation. cvc-pattern-valid. Value   is not facet-valid with respect to pattern `[A-Z][A-Z\- ]{0,3}` for type `PersonNameControlType`.

The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1]/efile:ReturnHeader[1]/efile:Filer[1]/efile:SpouseNameControlTxt[1]

Issue : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation. cvc-pattern-valid. Value   is not facet-valid with respect to pattern `[A-Z][A-Z\- ]{0,3}` for type `PersonNameControlType`.

The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1]/efile:ReturnData[1]/efile:IRS1040[1]/efile:ExemptSpouseNameControlTxt[1]

Issue : Business Rule X0000-005 - The XML data has failed schema validation. cvc-pattern-valid. Value   is not facet-valid with respect to pattern `([A-Za-z0-9`-] ?)*[A-Za-z0-9`\-]` for type `PersonNameType`.

The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return[1]/efile:ReturnData[1]/efile:IRS1040[1]/efile:ExemptSpouseNm[1]

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in the "no" checkbox of this question:

[image]

> At any time during 2021, did you receive, sell, exchange, or otherwise dispose of any financial interest in any virtual currency?

It incorrectly triggers some business rules that appear related to a checkbox for whether a spouse is exempt. When I unchecked this my submission via free file fillable forms (https://www.freefilefillableforms.com/home/default.php) was accepted. And yes -- that means apparently there's also no business rule enforced to ensure that exactly one of the boxes ("yes" or "no") is checked.

Comment: How on earth did you figure that out? It seems there's a lot of latency between a submission and receiving an error.